# Can we used Facebook for Analytics to send push notyfication with mobile browsers?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, facebook-analytics

Is anybody know can we used Facebook for Analytics on the WEB to send push notification from the mobile browser?

Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't presently possible to send web push notifications within mobile browsers with Facebook Analytics.